# Error while uploading image in lightning community

Tags: lightning, community

I am trying to upload image in lighnint community and trying to change logo of community but i am getting error when i select image from my files and click on uplaod image.
I have previously added 3 4 images and all those images are showing in asset library but now if i am trying to add any new image its not working.
I am getting folloowing error on image upload.[image]

anyone know about this kind of issues?

Comment: This error is coming from the trigger written on content document link please see what is the exception there.

Comment: Hey huff !!! u saved my day...!!! thanx..!!!!@AvijitChakraborty